# Building a WAR file with Bazel

Tags: java, web, bazel

I am trying to build a WAR file for a Java-based web application. The [AppEngine rules for Bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_appengine) seems to provide this functionality but I really don't need anything AppEngine-related. I searched all over the web but couldn't find a pointer to a built-in capability of Bazel nor a rule that would provide the functionality.

Can you point a viable solution that works similar to functionality available in Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom Bazel rule. You can find the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/bmuschko/rules_java_war).